# How to pass data from DataGridView to text boxs in another form?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I choose an item out of a combo box, then enter the quantity and the price and then i click add, from there it gets put into the datagrid.

When i select that item and click the edit button, i want the data from that cell to show in the text boxs on the edit form that appears.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use

> DataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells

then for each cell get the Value and then fill it into your edit-form.
You can pass it by the constructor of your editform:

```
public class EditForm : Form
{
   public EditForm(string ProductName, string Quantity, string Price, string Total)
   {
      /*set values to your controls/any vars*/
   }
}
```

(At the Combobox add your ProductName list as DataSource then select the item with the value of the cell)

Hope i could help.

**EDIT**
this only gives you the fist selected cell, so if you multiselect the others are ignored.
Also don't forget to check **if** something is selected otherwise you get a nice NullReferenceException ;)

Answer (score 0):

Send thou constructor of subForm

```
int id
```

then select from database where id = passed id.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use *static variable*... when you get that `id` or item name (click item and edit) use any disable `txtItem.text`

```
  txtItem.text = Datagridview1.databindings.Add("text",Datagridview1.Datasource,"Product");
```

this txtItem have now your Id or itemName. And the "Product" is the name of your datagridview1 field.

Now you code for static member

```
public static String str=txtItem.text;
```

on the next form where you want to use this use that simple code...

```
string val = form1.str;
```

and pass the value of `val` to *combobox*.

***it is the method to pass the value from one form to another by static variable.***